# How to return the hash result with limit size by using HASHBYTES function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can `HASHBYTES` function return the result which has limited size (e.g. to 20 characters) and make sure the hash result without collision ?

Syntax for SQL Server, Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Data Warehouse, Parallel Data Warehouse

```
HASHBYTES ( '<algorithm>', { @input | 'input' } )  

    <algorithm>::= MD2 | MD4 | MD5 | SHA | SHA1 | SHA2_256 | SHA2_512 

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA1', 'This is a test.');
```

it returns

```
0x0E7AAB0B4FF0FD2DFB4F0233E2EE7A26CD08F173
```

the length is too long. I am not sure the first 20 characters like 0x0E7AAB0B4FF0FD2DFB whether will have a collision with another input. Actually, I want to get the unique key from converting the input by using `HASHBYTES` function in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually, I want to get the unique key from converting the input by using HASHBYTES function in SQL Server

Your output may not be unique ,if you choose first 20 characters or some random characters

> Can HASHBYTES function return the result which has limited size (e.g. to 20 characters) and make sure the hash result without collision ?

We are not in control of length of the output

There are chances of collisions,when your input exceeds 8000 characters..If your input is below 8000 characters(max input limit),the chances of collisions are very rare and is not possible unless you have a super computer..

Google was able to achieve collisions for different inputs ,but this required below computing power

> This attack required over 9,223,372,036,854,775,808 SHA1 computations. This took the equivalent processing power as 6,500 years of single-CPU computations and 110 years of single-GPU computations

so you need not worry about collisions..Further you can choose an unique key,if you need uniqueness and not sure on input size..

**Update:**
just as an FYI:

Input length limitation has been removed from SQLServer 2016 SP1

References:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35219/choosing-the-right-algorithm-in-hashbytes-function
https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html

Comment: my input will be below 100 characters and I want the result returns 20 characters for unique key, how can I do ?

Comment: it's not possible to limit result set size and guarantee uniqueness

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @WLiu: when using SHA1, the result should have 20 bytes (varbinary). It is sometimes converted to the 40-character string that represents the hex value of the bytes (one byte, two hex numerals).